# How can I filter out certain combinations?

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, filter

I'm trying to filter the input of a TextBox using a *Regex*. I need up to three numbers before the decimal point and I need two after it. This can be in any form.

I've tried changing the regex commands around, but it creates errors and single inputs won't be valid. I'm using a TextBox in WPF to collect the data.

```
bool containsLetter = Regex.IsMatch(units.Text, "^[0-9]{1,3}([.] [0-9] {1,3})?$");
if (containsLetter == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}
return containsLetter;
```

I want the regex filter to accept these types of  inputs:

```
111.11,
11.11,
1.11,
1.01,
100,
10,
1,
```

Comment: Looks like all you have to do is remove the spaces from your regex pattern. Why did you add them in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

As it has been mentioned in the comment, spaces are characters that will be interpreted literally in your regex pattern.

Therefore in this part of your regex:

`([.] [0-9] {1,3})`

- a space is expected between `.` and `[0-9]`,
- the same goes for after `[0-9]` where the regex would match `1` to `3` spaces.

This being said, for readability purpose you have several way to construct your regex.

**1) Put the comments out of the regex:**

```
string myregex = @"\s" // Match any whitespace once
+ @"\n"  // Match one newline character
+ @"[a-zA-Z]";  // Match any letter
```

**2) Add comments within your regex by using the syntax** `(?#comment)`

> ```
> needle(?# this will find a needle)
> ```
>
> [Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=needle(%3F%23%20this%20will%20find%20a%20needle)&i=hayneedlestack)

**3) Activate free-spacing mode within your regex:**

> ```
> nee # this will find a nee...
> dle # ...dle (the split means nothing when white-space is ignored)
> ```
>
> doc: https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html
>
> [Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=nee%20%23%20this%20will%20find%20a%20nee...%0D%0Adle%20%23%20...dle%20(the%20split%20means%20nothing%20when%20white-space%20is%20ignored)&i=hayneedlestack&o=x)